# How to add Customer to wishlist programmatically?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

i am trying to add newly created customer to wishlist and show him one category related products. but i am not getting how to add customer to wishlist table programmatically. if customer is exist in wishlist table, it adds product in wishlist_item table.

So how can i add new customer to wishlist table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then you want to create a wishlist for a customer; You can use something like this:

```
$customerid= "YOUR CUSTOMER ID "; // Modify This
$customer=Mage::getModel("customer/customer")->load($customerid);
$wishlist=Mage::getModel("wishlist/wishlist")->loadByCustomer($customer,true);

Check for reference this: app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php
```